# Braze canvas - unable to receive emails

Tags: email, braze

I am trying to send more than 3 requests to my braze canvas from postman, immediately one ofter other. But I am not able to receive emails for all of the requests sent. I haven't setup frequency capping and customer re-entry time is 0sec. Can anyone help?

Edit: I found the Answer for this. Looks like Braze canvas cannot be used to send email to same person in succession. Braze Campaign is appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to submit your code? It should look something similar to:

```
{"api_key":"<api_key>",
"canvas_id":"<canvas ID>",
  "recipients":[
    {"external_user_id": "{{User}}",
      "canvas_entry_properties":{
        "<any additional entry criteria>": "<values>"}}]}
```

That would allow you to push a single user. If the external_user_id does not appear in your instance when searched, it may not send. 
https://www.braze.com/docs/api/endpoints/messaging/send_messages/post_send_triggered_canvases/#request-body

The information passed for the Canvas via the API must match up to the filters in Braze, otherwise it won't send. Make sure your API key can deploy Canvases as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.Apparently, Braze campaign cannot be used to send email in succession to a single user. Switching it to Braze canvas solved the issue.